# How to respond to an (unlikely) call for (emergency) help?

Tags: discussion, questions, ethics

Today something odd happened. A user posted a ["question"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41937659/revisions) titled "*Beaten daily on the regular*" tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and the body repeatedly said:

> i am beaten on a daily basis, my name is (name). help me

The question was immediately downvoted (+2/-9) and removed by the Community robot, but I was wondering what we should do in the case this is indeed a person asking for help.

I searched the Internet and there seem to be a lot of people called "(name)". Furthermore I could not find a meme or running joke about a (name) looking for help, etc.

I am wondering what we should/could do in this (and future cases). Although the odds are perhaps very unlikely that this is a person asking for help, I feel a bit responsible to react in cases where there are people that try to find a way out of some kind of hell.

As humans I think we are obliged to react in case there is a serious possibility and simply downvoting/deleting the post is not going to help since the person can be risking a lot by posting here anyway. I'm not saying this is the case here, but in general there *can/will* be such cases.

Any remarks/solutions to this ethical dilemma?

Comment: For me this looks just as a troll. Ask yourself if you would need help, would you ask for help on a programming site?!

Comment: Stack Overflow is the wrong venue for anything like this.

Comment: @Rizier123: no but there have been cases reported where people who could not speak up found an escape by ordering pizza, etc.

Comment: Was there any contact information in the question? If you felt the need, you could contact them. If not, what could we do?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: no there was no contact information. This question is more general what we could do in the future in case this scenario is repeated.

Comment: @Rizier123 In the (insanely unlikely) scenario where I had maybe 5 minutes to find a way to get a message of help out and the internet was my only option, I'd probably type the first address that came to mind where I could post/message someone. That could (also insanely unlikely) be Stack Overflow. But I agree that it's much, much more likely to be a troll or some other form of poor joke. (Though if staff or mods saw, they may have been inclined to pass it on to authorities anyway.)

Comment: Mod flag and let them know about it?  Unlike us mere mortals they can see the contact information.

Comment: related: [What's the official SE response to serious mentions of suicide in posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243701/165773) "I hate to sound callous about this, but... This isn't a support group; y'all probably aren't trained to deal with the outpouring of grief and despair of someone you've never met and may have absolutely nothing in common with. I'm certainly not. Indeed, there's a decent chance that leaving a post like this around could end up just making things worse..."

Comment: @Kendra Even then I hope you would write something more useful than the same sentence like 30 times. Stuff that could help to help the person in need of help.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I indeed raised a flag with the message "weird post...", did not receive a response except that the flag was "helpful".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thats probably the only response you will get.  Normally though that means what needs to be done has been done

Comment: @Rizier123 Oh yes, I'd be giving much more useful information. Your original query was, though, if someone would actually ask for help on a programming site if they needed help. :) It's possible, though unlikely. And highly pointless without more information.

Comment: Look this question is not about this specific case, but more in general the procedure we should follow in case this happens *again*. Raising a flag to the moderators is probably indeed the best we can do.

Comment: *"As humans I think we are obliged to react in case there is a serious possibility"* - fully agreed. But this isn't a serious possibility. At best this is an unlikely possibility. The question is more: can you move yourself to let it go?

Comment: @Gimby: as said before (and the comment above), I am talking about a general case... For instance someone asks help and provides some (basic) contact information or hides it in their profile.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've noticed on Meta that if you want to ask about a generic case don't include an example. People attach onto that particular example and ignore the general case.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: apparently. Well of course the specific event *triggered* my question. But [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243700/181776) also mentions a specific case. But in the future it is indeed probably wise to swap the paragraphs and first ask the general case and perhaps mention the triggering example.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can't say beyond a shadow of a doubt if this is some genuine plea for help from a real person, or if this is someone trolling or spewing nonsense.

The only thing that makes sense to do is to flag it for moderator attention.  There's nothing you can extract out of it to even take action on, if it *were* genuine.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side one could comment recommending to seek help through the usual channels. I don't say you have, but it wouldn't hurt either and it might take some time until a moderator sees it (not sure how long that takes on average). Also I wonder a bit what a moderator will then do with such a thing.

Comment: in PAREnting site , handled once an issue for a women got beaten in egypt, that site can help in particular cases

Comment: Agree to flag to moderators who can see IP address and then report to the local authority that covers that country and area for them to consider acting upon.

Comment: This just begs the question as to what the moderator policy should be for cases like this. I think it should be to make every effort to help the person, meaning contact them if that's possible in any way in order to follow up, and if they leave an address, contact the police for that city and notify them of the situation. Of course, in the case the OP is talking about, there's really nothing anyone can do (unless moderators have access to some secret private messaging feature).

Comment: @JackM Moderators [do have the ability](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119106/185080) to send private messages to users and to invite users into a chat room and make the room private. (Btw: I don't really agree with the "beyond the shadow of a doubt" part of this answer--that's an [evidentiary standard required to convict someone in court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_the_shadow_of_a_doubt), and is definitely no prerequisite to acting on reports of abuse or other emergency. With that said, I've +1'd the answer; I believe the recommendation here is entirely correct: *flag for a mod*.)

Answer (score 4):

There are two possibilities.

1. They are a troll - 
   We need to remove the post ASAP because it's crap, it's off-topic, and it makes light of serious issues.

   Also, we want to protect mandatory reporters from annoying situations.
   There are people who are required by law to report possible child abuse and such. 
   I do not know the exact boundaries for when they are required to report, but it's feasible that this kind of post might count, thereby putting them in a bad situation.
2. They are not a troll

   1. Can we identify their physical location?
   2. Do we know their name?
   3. Do we know the name of the person who is allegedly doing this?
   4. Do we know the appropriate agency/group to report to?

1, 2, and 3 are all maybe's, based mostly on public self-reporting. 1 could be deduced from IP address, but that could be as broad as an entire university. There is absolutely no guarantee that anybody on SO knows 4 (although it's likely that somebody does.)
Therefore, **SO is not guaranteed to be able to help at all**.

Furthermore, and this is a big point, the information available in 1, 2,and 3 would be sufficient for the abuser to recognize the victim.
**It would be quite dangerous for anybody to try and reach out for help here**, 
since we are not setup to provide the public anonymity victims need while still providing the SO community with the information it would need to be helpful.

Therefore, since SO is a bad place to seek this kind of help, we should allow the community to discourage such attempts, even if they are genuine.

***There are legitimate places where victims of abuse can find help. SO is not currently one of those, and it is not setup to ever become one.***